# Deserialising json with JSON.NET - Cannot deserialise because the type requires a JSON array

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Trying to read json via an API but getting the following error: I've tried a few things but always seem to get this error..

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type     'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Shared.Review]' because the type requires a JSON array     (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'status', line 1, position 10.
```

Model:

```
public class Reviewer
{
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string verified_buyer { get; set; }
    public string profile_picture { get; set; }
}

public class Review
{
    public string product_review_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string review { get; set; }
    public string rating { get; set; }
    public string date_created { get; set; }
    public string timeago { get; set; }
    public string date_formatted { get; set; }
    public string product { get; set; }
    public List<object> ratings { get; set; }
    public Reviewer reviewer { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public List<Review> reviews { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public string rating { get; set; }
    public string per_page { get; set; }
    public string current_page { get; set; }
    public int total_pages { get; set; }
}
```

c# Code:

```
  var reviews = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Review>>(json);
  StringBuilder reviewsString = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (var review in reviews)
  {
       reviewsString.AppendFormat("<div class=\"review\">");
       reviewsString.AppendFormat("<p class=\"review-title\">Snugg Case</p>");
       reviewsString.AppendFormat("<div class=\"rating\">");
       reviewsString.AppendFormat("<span class=\"star\"></span>");
       reviewsString.AppendFormat("<span class=\"star\"></span>");
       reviewsString.AppendFormat("<span class=\"star\"></span>");
       reviewsString.AppendFormat("<span class=\"star\"></span>");
       reviewsString.AppendFormat("<span class=\"halfStar\"></span>");
       reviewsString.AppendFormat("</div>");
       reviewsString.AppendFormat("<p class=\"review-details\">{0}</p>",
                                                         review.review);
       reviewsString.AppendFormat("<p class=\"review-name\">{0}</p>",
                                                           review.name);
       reviewsString.AppendFormat("<p class=\"review-date\">{0}</p>",
                                                 review.date_formatted);
       reviewsString.AppendFormat("</div>  ");
       topSectionReviews.Text += reviewsString;
   }
```

Example Json:

http://pastebin.com/HNhNDMhr

Any questions just ask

Thanks in advance,

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to deserialize into a collection:

```
var reviews = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Review>>(json);
```

However your Json isn't a collection at the top level since that would mean the json string would start and end with `[]`. Instead it is surrounded by `{}` which indicates a single object.

It looks like you want to deserialize as a single `RootObject` instead:

```
var reviews = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

since this has a field `List<Review> reviews` and `string status`.

Not that you are not following naming conventions. Use proper naming and the `[JsonProperty("something")]` attribute to correctly parse the json.